# Gradient of a vector on a triangulated lattice

Tags: numerical-analysis

Suppose I have a triangulated mesh and I have solved a differential equation problem and have a solution phi. From phi I can construct a vector field, how would I go about computing the gradient of this vector field?

The mesh looks something like this. phi is solved for at the center of all of the cells in the picture.

[image]

I'm not sure how to handle the spatial discretization for a triangulated lattice. Any references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a least squares method to calculate the gradient on unstructured meshes.  Here's a presentation on the method. [least squares gradient](https://engineering.purdue.edu/ME608/webpage/l16.pdf)

Comment: Does this method by itself work for computing the gradient of a vector?

Comment: The url doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The gradient of a vector field is simply a matrix where each row is the gradient of one of the (scalar) components of your vector field. In other words, if you know how to compute the gradient of a scalar solution, you also know how to compute the gradient of a vector field.

Of course, on a triangular mesh with piecewise linear elements, the gradient is then simply a constant on every cell.

Comment: What are piecewise linear elements?

Comment: Err, the most elementary elements, with the usual hat functions as shape functions.

Comment: Here's some stuff on shape functions for those like myself who have never heard of these before. [Basic explanation of shape functions.](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10678/basic-explanation-of-shape-function). @WolfgangBangerth I plan to check out Lecture 4 of yours. Thanks for the pointers.